# How To Prevent from rounding numbers in Liquid

Tags: shopify, liquid

I'm trying to calculate growth rate between two months and I'm getting round numbers instead of floating. Is there a way to prevent liquid from rounding numbers?

{{ articles_created_this_month_count | minus: articles_created_last_month_count | divided_by: articles_created_last_month_count | times: 100 }}%

{{ articles_created_this_month_count | minus: articles_created_last_month_count | divided_by: articles_created_last_month_count | times: 100 }}%

Comment: I've already found a solution.
{{ author.articles_created_this_month_count | minus: author.articles_created_last_month_count | times: 100.0 | divided_by: author.articles_created_last_month_count | round: 2 }}%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with many programming languages, when Liquid divides an integer with an integer, the result will always be an integer again. So `5 / 2` will equal `2`. But `5.0 / 2` will be `2.5`. So you could multiple your `articles_created_this_month_count` with `1.0`:

```
{{ articles_created_this_month_count | times: 1.0 | minus: articles_created_last_month_count | divided_by: articles_created_last_month_count | times: 100 }}
```

Answer (score -1):

use javascript for pet projects like this where Liquid is not appropriate